# Outlook VBA "The attempted operation failed"

Tags: vba, outlook

I have followed the instructions at http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/saveatt.htm to save attachments from emails in a specific folder to another folder. When I run this code I get the error:

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Please note and report the following information.
>
> Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder
>
> Error Number: -2147221233
>
> Error Description: The attempted operation failed.  An object could
>   not be found.

New to macros, so don't know where the error may be. Any advice?

The code is below:

```
Sub Test()

    SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "MyFolder", "xls", ""

End Sub

Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, DestFolder As String)
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    I = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If DestFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.Item("mydocuments")
        DestFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(DestFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder DestFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If I > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```

Comment: comment the line `On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err` and then tell us which line is giving you the error?

Comment: That pointed out the error. See answer...Or seeing as I can't answer my own question yet...The problem was that the folder I specified wasn't actually created within the Inbox, it was at the same level as the Inbox and so it couldn't find the folder. Simple things...

Comment: Sorry couldn't add answer yet, see comment above.

Comment: You should be able to add an answer soon. :)

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.

"The problem was that the folder I specified wasn't actually created within the Inbox, it was at the same level as the Inbox and so it couldn't find the folder. Simple things..." [chinvpl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2959781/chinvpl)